# Dispose called mysteriously on my object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am experiencing a weird issue:

I have an object that (in a simplified view) looks like this:

```
public class LogService : ILogProvider
{
    private ServiceHost host;

    public void Open()
    {
        // Open Service
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This object is being referenced as a field on some other class.

Occasionally in my application, i am recreating the service (which i guess causes the LogService object to be collected).

However, i am seeing that the Dispose() method of LogService is being called, although i do not call it directly ANYWHERE in my codebase!

Debugging this, the caller in Visual Studio "Call Stack" is "external" so i cannot view it.

What can cause this? when it is being called, the host field is null, and it throws a nullreference.

Here's the callstack of the failure:

> > Executer.dll!Executer.LogService.Dispose() Line 54 + 0x6 bytes  C#      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.InstanceProvider.ReleaseInstance(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext
> >     instanceContext, object instance) + 0x25 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.ReleaseInstance(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext
> >     instanceContext, object instance) + 0x35 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.SetUserObject(object
> >     newUserObject) + 0x4e bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.Unload()
> >     + 0xf bytes       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.OnClose(System.TimeSpan
> >     timeout) + 0x1f bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(System.TimeSpan
> >     timeout) + 0x172 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.CloseIfNotBusy()
> >     + 0x76 bytes      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.NotifyEmpty(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext
> >     instanceContext) + 0xb bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.OnEmpty()
> >     + 0x16 bytes      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.LifetimeManager.DecrementBusyCount()
> >     + 0xbc bytes      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.ChannelRemoved(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannel
> >     channel) + 0x37 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.RemoveChannel(System.ServiceModel.Channels.IChannel
> >     channel) + 0x42 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.OnChannelClosed(object
> >     sender, System.EventArgs args) + 0x16 bytes
> >       System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnClosed()
> >     + 0xd5 bytes      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
> >     + 0xcf bytes      System.ServiceModel.dll!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnInnerChannelFaulted(object
> >     sender, System.EventArgs e) + 0x46 bytes

Comment: Test if `host` is not `null` before disposing it. Also please post the part of your code that actually uses your `LogService` class.

Comment: Are you wrapping the creation of `LogService` in `using` statements anywhere?

Comment: Maybe the Application Pool is recycled. Is the service running on IIS?

Comment: Is the ILogProvider implementing IDisposable?

Comment: Martijn is right. We need to know if this is the standard IDisposable.Dispose() or some non-standards-compliant Dispose();

Comment: @MartijnB According to Microsoft, [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.logprovider.aspx).

Comment: Set your debugger to 'Show External Code', then add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the OP didn't mentioned anything about that class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: How did you get there? ;p

Comment: @MartijnB Well, OPs are like that: they often forget to mention really important things :)

Comment: ILogProvider is an interface, not a class. I will add the external stacktrace.

Comment: Added stack trace. It seems when the channel is faulted, it will somehow call Dispose. Can anyone confirm ?

Comment: @liortal: It could be. Try hardcoding a fault to confirm :)

Comment: I think i know what is going on. The class that holds the reference to ServiceHost is also the service implementation. I guess ServiceHost will dispose that class on failure. This was a 1,2 hack just to get it up and running. I need to create the service host elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the answer for you but have this thoughts. You could be right. This means that the ServiceHost is disposed before the LogService.

Now if that's true then I don't understand why the ServiceHost in your LogService is null. This can only be by if the dispose of the ServiceHost will also null all references to it. This I find hard to believe but could also be a lack of my knowledge (maybe someone can confirm). So I created a little test which should verify this by throwing a null reference exception, which it doesn't.

```
public interface ILogProvider : IDisposable
{
    void Open();
}

public class LogService : ILogProvider
{
    private readonly ServiceHost host;

    public LogService(ServiceHost host)
    {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        // Open Service
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        host.Dispose();
    }
}

public class ServiceHost : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~ServiceHost()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //do managed cleanup
        }

        // do unmanaged cleanup here            
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost();

        using (LogService log = new LogService(host))
        {
            host.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The test first disposes the `ServiceHost` and after that the dispose of the `LogService` is called without throwing a exception. So unless the dispose of the `ServiceHost` is radically implemented differently (which easily could be) you have to check how the `LogService` is created. Does it really always has a reference to `ServiceHost`?

Hoped this helped you to get in the right direction. Also please provide the answer if you resolved it.